# Car was not falling down on the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, my player's car is not falling on the ground when it is out of the track.
This kind of situation happens when you move out of the track:

[image]

It should fall down on the ground but it didn't, it is flying in the same height of the track.

I am using this code to move the player's car.

```
    appliedSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 10f;
    appliedSpeed = Mathf.Min(appliedSpeed, speed);
    myRigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * appliedSpeed;
```

If the player car falls on the ground then there is a game over but currently, this is not happening with me :)

Gravity is already applied in the project settings and you can check my rigidbody settings in the above image.

Now give me some suggestion to apply some gravity to my player car.

Answer (score 0):

I think transform.forward is causing this situation, because transform.forward is just a way to say "new Vector3(0,0,1)", and applying this to the rigidBody velocity is causing the car to float, Because the Y axis velocity is equal to 0.

you could try to add to the velocity using the "+=" operator instead of just applying the value directly to the rigidbody velocity